# PYQT How to paint QGraphicsTextItem properly

Tags: python, pyqt4

```
class TextItem(QGraphicsTextItem):

    def __init__(self,text):
        QGraphicsTextItem.__init__(self,text)
        self.text=text
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)



    def paint(self,painter,option,widget):
        self.pen = QPen()
        self.pen.setWidth(2)
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
```

I can paint QGraphicsTextItem. But the problem is.... Text in QGraphicsTextItem disappear when I paint it. How can I solve?

Comment: You don't seem to be painting the text - just the Rect.  Just do a `drawText`

Comment: I didn't do that, because I already set Text like this QGraphicsTextItem.__init__(self,text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overriding the `paint` method supplied by the parent `QGraphicsTextItem` class you are saying you aren't going to use how it paints its text.  Instead you are implementing your own text painting.  But then you don't actually paint any text and so no text appears on screen.

If you want to control all the painting yourself then you are going to need to add at least something like:

```
painter.drawText(self.boundingRect(),self.text)
```

Or you could perhaps call

```
QGraphicsTextItem.paint(self,painter,option,widget)
```

at the end of your own painting depending on the effect you are looking for.